# UITableViewCell - How to get a pointer to the reorder control?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can get a reference to the cell quite easily

```
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

But I need to get a reference to the little handle on the righthand side of the cell when in edit/reorder mode. How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure at all, but maybe try `cell.editingAccessoryView` ? (returns a `UIView`).

Comment: This correct, how can I mark it as correct?

Comment: I'll post an answer now so you can upvote/accept it, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `editingAccessoryView` property on your cell :

```
cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
UIView *editingAccessory = cell.editingAccessoryView;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find it with this code, but the reorder-control is private-api

```
for (UIView *view in cell.subviews) {
    if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"]) {
        // 'view' is the reorder control
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I need a public method